# How to merge two buffers containing questions and answers

Tags: list

In my line of work, I often have one document containing questions and another document containing answers.  How can I merge these documents in the form of Question/Answer.

BUFFER #1:

```
Q1:  Do you like green eggs and ham?
Q2:  Would you like them here or there?
Q3:  Would you like them in a house?
```

BUFFER #2:

```
A1:  I do not like them, Sam-I-am.
A2:  I would not like them here or there.
A3:  I do not like them in a house.
```

DESIRED RESULT -- BUFFER #3:

```
Q1:  Do you like green eggs and ham?
A1:  I do not like them, Sam-I-am.
Q2:  Would you like them here or there?
A2:  I would not like them here or there.
Q3:  Would you like them in a house?
A3:  I do not like them in a house.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I would do that, copy&paste both Q&As into a new buffer (`#3`) then

```
Q1:  Do you like green eggs and ham?
Q2:  Would you like them here or there?
Q3:  Would you like them in a house?
A1:  I do not like them, Sam-I-am.
A2:  I would not like them here or there.
A3:  I do not like them in a house.
```

do the following:

```
beginning-of-buffer (M-<)
kmacro-start-macro (f3)
    next-line x3 (3 C-n)
    kill-whole-line (C-S-BS)
    previous-line x2 (2 C-p)
    yank (C-y)
kmacro-end-macro (f4)
kmacro-call-macro x2 (2 f4)
```

If you often need to do this then to implement a function may be an option:

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  (let ((Qs (with-current-buffer "#1" (split-string (buffer-string) "\n")))
        (As (with-current-buffer "#2" (split-string (buffer-string) "\n"))))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "#3")
      (dolist (Q Qs)
        (insert Q "\n")
        (insert (pop As) "\n")))))
```

Comment: I tried `foo` and it works well.  I'll leave the question open for another day or so to see if there are any other interesting answers, and I'll need a cup of coffee to wrap my head around `foo`.  I'm not sure why it's a bit of a brain-twister for me; but I'm sure some coffee after a good night sleep will help.  Thank you for posting an answer -- greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1. A classic use-case for keyboard macros -- but why bother copying and pasting all the text into the new buffer first? You can do your buffer switching within the macro definition! (Using keyboard macros to read and manipulate text across *multiple buffers* is an amazingly powerful paradigm. Slightly easier to mess up in the recording phase, admittedly, but well worth being familiar with.)

Comment: Exactly! Seems good to remember > You can do your buffer switching within the macro definition